# Remove Placeholder from TextInputLayout in Xamarin Forms for Android & IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to create Suggestion Searchbar using Entry

[image]

i was able to create the suggestion searchbar but i am not able to change the look of this Entry, i want to remove the tooltip above (Search by Speciality..) and just want it to look like other entry in the app

could anyone help me what and where i had to make change for getting that look

here is my code

Xamarin Android :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AutoCompleteViewv2), 
typeof(AutoCompleteViewRendererv2))]
namespace App.Droid.Renderers.RevisedRenderer
{
 public class AutoCompleteViewRendererv2 : 
FormsAppCompat.ViewRenderer<AutoCompleteViewv2, TextInputLayout>
{
    public AutoCompleteViewRendererv2(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    private AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView NativeControl => Control?.EditText 
 as AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView;

    protected override TextInputLayout CreateNativeControl()
    {
        var textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(Context);
        var autoComplete = new AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView(Context)
        {              
            BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(GetPlaceholderColor()),
            Text = Element?.Text,
            Hint = Element?.Placeholder,
        };

        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        autoComplete.SetBackground(gd);
        if (Element != null)
        {
            autoComplete.SetHintTextColor(Element.PlaceholderColor.ToAndroid());
            autoComplete.SetTextColor(Element.TextColor.ToAndroid());             
        }
        textInputLayout.AddView(autoComplete);
        return textInputLayout;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AutoCompleteViewv2> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // unsubscribe
            NativeControl.ItemClick -= AutoCompleteOnItemSelected;
            var elm = e.OldElement;
            elm.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            SetNativeControl(CreateNativeControl());
            // subscribe
            SetItemsSource();
            SetThreshold();
            KillPassword();
            NativeControl.TextChanged += (s, args) => Element.RaiseTextChanged(NativeControl.Text);
            NativeControl.ItemClick += AutoCompleteOnItemSelected;

            var elm = e.NewElement;
            elm.CollectionChanged += ItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == Entry.IsPasswordProperty.PropertyName)
            KillPassword();
        if (e.PropertyName == AutoCompleteViewv2.ItemsSourceProperty.PropertyName)
            SetItemsSource();
        else if (e.PropertyName == AutoCompleteViewv2.ThresholdProperty.PropertyName)
            SetThreshold();
    }

    private void AutoCompleteOnItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
    {
        var view = (AutoCompleteTextView)sender;
        var selectedItemArgs = new SelectedItemChangedEventArgs(view.Text);
        var element = (AutoCompleteViewv2)Element;
        element.OnItemSelectedInternal(Element, selectedItemArgs);
    }

    private void ItemsSourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var element = (AutoCompleteViewv2)Element;
        ResetAdapter(element);
    }

    private void KillPassword()
    {
        if (Element.IsPassword)
            throw new NotImplementedException("Cannot set IsPassword on a AutoComplete");
    }

    private void ResetAdapter(AutoCompleteViewv2 element)
    {
        var adapter = new BoxArrayAdapter(Context,
            Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line,
            element.ItemsSource.ToList(),
            element.SortingAlgorithm);
        NativeControl.Adapter = adapter;

        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void SetItemsSource()
    {
        var element = (AutoCompleteViewv2)Element;
        if (element.ItemsSource == null) return;

        ResetAdapter(element);
    }

    private void SetThreshold()
    {
        var element = (AutoCompleteViewv2)Element;
        NativeControl.Threshold = element.Threshold;
    }

    #region Section 2
    protected AColor GetPlaceholderColor() => Element.PlaceholderColor.ToAndroid(Color.FromHex("#80000000"));
    #endregion
}

internal class BoxArrayAdapter : ArrayAdapter
{
    private readonly IList<string> _objects;
    private readonly Func<string, ICollection<string>, ICollection<string>> _sortingAlgorithm;

    public BoxArrayAdapter(
        Context context,
        int textViewResourceId,
        List<string> objects,
        Func<string, ICollection<string>, ICollection<string>> sortingAlgorithm) : base(context, textViewResourceId, objects)
    {
        _objects = objects;
        _sortingAlgorithm = sortingAlgorithm;
    }

    public override Filter Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return new CustomFilter(_sortingAlgorithm) { Adapter = this, Originals = _objects };
        }
    }
}

internal class CustomFilter : Filter
{
    private readonly Func<string, ICollection<string>, ICollection<string>> _sortingAlgorithm;

    public CustomFilter(Func<string, ICollection<string>, ICollection<string>> sortingAlgorithm)
    {
        _sortingAlgorithm = sortingAlgorithm;
    }

    public BoxArrayAdapter Adapter { private get; set; }
    public IList<string> Originals { get; set; }

    protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
    {
        var results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.Length() == 0)
        {
            results.Values = new Java.Util.ArrayList(Originals.ToList());
            results.Count = Originals.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            var values = new Java.Util.ArrayList();
            var sorted = _sortingAlgorithm(constraint.ToString(), Originals).ToList();

            for (var index = 0; index < sorted.Count; index++)
            {
                var item = sorted[index];
                values.Add(item);
            }

            results.Values = values;
            results.Count = sorted.Count;
        }

        return results;
    }

    protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
    {
        if (results.Count == 0)
            Adapter.NotifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else
        {
            Adapter.Clear();
            var vals = (Java.Util.ArrayList)results.Values;
            foreach (var val in vals.ToArray())
            {
                Adapter.Add(val);
            }
            Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

}

how can i get rid of that tooltip or placeholder and make the text in middle

Comment: This is how TextInputLayout on Android behaves. Why don't you just use the built in `Entry` if it is what you want it to behave like?

Comment: @Cheesebaron i want to add suggestion AutoCompleteViewv2 to my control how can i do that please let me know if you have any reference which i can follow

Comment: Do you want to remove the levitation feature of placeholder？

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT yes and also the placeholder and space used by placeholder

Comment: do you try to setHintEnable to false？

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT i tried but it throws an error with Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.EditText.getHint()' on a null object reference

Comment: I didn't try it with the renderer, but it worked with the TextInputLayout setHintEnabled false in Xamarin Android

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT setHintEnabled false throws an error to me still i will give a try again

Comment: yes,I'll also try it in the renderer